# How can I display Stripe PaymentElement form without creating Payment Intent first?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm building a platform for selling video courses using React and Next.js.

My goal is to create a payment form that unauthenticated users can use. I want it to work the way it works on Gumroad - a user opens a modal where they can enter their email, their credit card info, and click "Pay" (see the image). When the user submits this form, I want to create an account for them behind the scenes and process the payment at the same time, and then redirect them to the already purchased course, with them being already logged in to their account. That way the UX is much nicer, and conversions are higher - I don't have to require users to create an account before purchasing the course, to them it all looks like one step.

The problem is that to handle payments, I'm using `<PaymentElement />`. In order to display this form on my website, I am required to create a Payment Intent first. In order to create a Payment Intent, I have to pass it `stripeCustomerId` (so that I could save the payment method the user has used), as well as `userId` (so that, in my webhooks, after the payment succeeds, I could add the course to the list of the courses the user has purchased).  And that means that in order for me to display the checkout form, the user has to already have an account and be authenticated.

Can you give me some advice? What can I do, is there a solution or a workaround to this?

What I need is:

- Show the user a form where they can enter their email address and credit card info.
- When the user clicks "pay", create an account for them (which has `userId` and `stripeCustomerId`).
- After that, use this information to process the payment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can [update the Payment Intent's `customer` after the Payment Intent is created and/or confirmed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update#update_payment_intent-customer).  That means the flow would look something like this:

1. Create a Payment Intent
2. Display the payment page with the Payment Element
3. When payment successfully completes create a Customer and update the Payment Intent's `customer` with the Customer ID

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to add a new card information, we should follow that order

- Create a new customer on Stripe (using email, first name, lastname, phone, zipcode, etc)
- Create a setup intent, get a client secret
- Confirm card setup with the client secret (when adding card info)

The payment process comes after with that card info. You can make that new card as default if you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **guest user** first
2. Create a payment intent using guest user credentials
3. Display Stripe form on the client
4. Whenever the user submits the form on the client, update the payment intent with the customer id first then confirm the payment.